# Extract row value where the 2 columns are not equal in a data frame in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to extract values in the dataframe when the columns values are not equal

```
df
ColA  Colb  ColC
12     12    fs
23     24    fsd
34     34    dsf
21     22    dsf
```

Here 2nd and 4th Row values(ColA and ColB are not equal), So is there a way to extract row values and cell values corresponding to that?

```
Row values
2, 4
```

```
Cel_value_ColC  # Corresponding values
fsd, dsf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(ColA - ColB != 0) %>%
   pull(ColC)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can take the rows where colA-colB are not = 0

```
df$ColC[df$ColA-df$Colb != 0]
[1] fsd dsf
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach that does not require any subtraction:

```
row.values <- which(df$ColA != df$Colb)
row.values
#[1] 2 4

Cel_value_ColC <- df[df$ColA != df$Colb,"ColC"]
Cel_value_ColC
#[1] fsd dsf
```